# Managing Tk widgets?

Tags: ruby, perl, tk-toolkit

I really like tk, but one issue I have with it is how to cleanly manage all of the widgets. If I create 20 widgets, I have 20 variables, or usually I create a hash where I store them all. More recently, I created a class that has parent/child relationship, where I can create a parent object, like a frame, and add the child widgets to it which looks basically like this:

```
parent = TkObject.new(TkRoot.new)
parent.add("MAIN_FRAME", TkFrame.new.pack)
parent.child("MAIN_FRAME").add("SUBMIT", TkButton.new(:text => "Submit").pack)
```

This I find keeps things organized, but I end up with really long strings to access widgets. I am trying to find out if there is a better way to do this, and if I am trying to reinvent the wheel with my class mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Tk's internal names for widgets work very much like that as it happens, but a quite workable solution is to keep just the handles of the “interesting” widgets around (typically in a hash). Then you just use that the handle to that hash as an object in your program, so that you can directly refer to the parts that are interesting (so, with Perl syntax):

```perl
$thing->{submit}->invoke();
```

Of course, if you're accessing into an object a lot like that, especially from outside the implementation of the object, you probably should create a method to look after it. It adds a little performance cost, but keeps things much cleaner (Law of Demeter and all that).

The whole trick to dealing with all this is to treat all the complexity like swimming in the ocean; it doesn't matter how deep the water is, as long as you're only swimming on the surface. (If you're really needing huge amounts of nesting, you're probably doing it wrong; GUIs *mostly* work better when they're *not* very nested.)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I do. I guess I was hoping there was a cleaner way. I have also been trying FXruby but this does not seem to be any better in this regard.

Comment: @Eric: That's pretty clean actually. It's very difficult to come up with anything much cleaner than that given the nature of Perl's (or Ruby's) semantics; the object handle has to be _somewhere_.